# How can I derive the distribution of parameters from data?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, likelihood, posterior

For example, I know that my data comes from some normal distribution. I have data - measures (5.5, 4.9, 4.4, 5.3). Is it possible to tell the probability that the mean is less than 5? More generally, is it possible to derive the distribution of a parameter from the data?

I was thinking that the distribution of the mean could be proportional to the likelihood function, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Yes, but in likelihood/frequentist inference parameters are just unknown numbers, you should use bayesian inference. The posterior distribution of the mean is proportional to the likelihood function if the prior is constant (uniform).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no; you cannot derive the distribution of the parameter from a knowledge of the data alone.  It is important to remember that the prior is the distribution of your beliefs.  Imagine that you had beliefs about the location of $\mu$, and they are inconveniently bell-shaped.  If they are not flat, then your likelihood will not be proportionate to your posterior.  Calculating them as if flat is discarding real information and irrational.  Additionally, there are quite a few cases where using a flat prior results in a posterior that does not integrate to one.

Comment: (+1) But there's a considerable body of work on *uninformative/objective/default/ignorance/weak* priors, which perhaps shouldn't appear to be dismissed out of hand as "irrational". At the very least, they can be a way to get intervals with decent coverage from a frequentist perspective.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica There is a ton of work on uninformative priors, I agree.  But why would I want a Bayesian method with good Frequentist properties when I can use a Frequentist method with perfect Frequentist properties?  And, I am using the word "Irrational" in the technical sense.  Because of the axiomatic construction of Bayesian methods either in preference theory, Aristotelian logic, or gambling, it follows from the mathematics that it is irrational to throw away information.

Comment: There aren't frequentist methods as such, just a collection of criteria to judge intervals, point estimators, test statistics, &c according to their long-term performance under repeated sampling; if satisfaction of certain of those criteria may be deemed to entail perfection, then perfection is attainable only in special cases. So Bayesian procedures  in which priors are derived from the formal structure of the problem, rather than representing beliefs about parameter values, can be judged as any other procedure, & won't necessarily be found wanting.

Answer (score 0):

We know that we can derive the confidence interval (CI) of the mean for a specified confidence level (CL), based on a data set. Note that the CI actually is the interval such that the real mean is within this interval with the probability equals CL.

Back to your first question. To my understanding, your first question is equivalent to ask: based on the data set you have, is it possible to find out the corresponding CL when the one-tail CI is specified ?

I think it is possible. From your data set, r = [5.5, 4.9, 4.4, 5.3], we have n = 4, avrg(r) = 5.025, std(r) = 0.4856.
it can be calculated that the probability that the real mean below 5 equals:

t_cdf(a,n-1) = 0.4622,

where, a = (5 - avrg(r)) * sqrt(n)/std(r), and 't_cdf()' is the CDF of Student (i.e. t) distribution.